# what is the easiest way to mapping Tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a db on Customer Support.
there are 4 tables with some attributes like:
CustomerTable(Id,Name etc)
ProductTable(Id, Name, Price etc)
Order_History(Id, Name, OrderDate, total Price, CustomerId etc)
Order_details(Id, ProductId, Quantity etc)

Now i have to find out Customer Name, Product Name Date, Quantity by SQL Query.

Comment: Which Db are you using?

Comment: @JamesKn I'm not sure that's entirely relevant to the question at hand. Ultimately, the answer is s/he needs to use a join regardless of the DBMS being used.

Comment: @jbowman fair point but would useful to point them to right documentation. ;)

Comment: @JamesKn Agreed! But I have a sneaking suspicion this is a homework problem and no actual database is being used ;)

Comment: Sorry to not Response in due time. your Idea is Totally wrong @JamesKn, @ jbowman . I am using MS SQL for a demo project.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a full set of schema, so it's hard to give an exact query, but as far as I can tell from what you've provided you'll need to use a join between all of your tables, and reduce the result set by limiting each result row of the cross product to such that links all four tables by foreign key:

```
SELECT CustomerTable.Name, ProductTable.Name, Order_History.OrderDate, Order_details.Quantity 
FROM CustomerTable, Order_History, Order_details, ProductTable 
WHERE CustomerTable.Id = Order_History.CustomerId AND Order_History.DetailsId = Order_details.ID AND ProductTable.Id = Order_details.ProductId;
```

Note that I've assumed that there is a foreign key relation between Order_History and Order_details (`Order_History.DetailsId = Order_details.ID`) which you haven't specified. If such a relation does not exist you'll need to create one for this query to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this following

```
select c.name,p.name,od.quantity
from customertable c
join Order_History oh  on c.id = oh.customerid
join Order_details od  on oh.orderid = od.orderid
join ProductTable p  on od.productid = p.id;
```

If you want to use the where condition you can mention that at last line in your query